# Navigation through pages on time

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am working on JSF application, where i am using datatable to show list of records. I have used ajax paginator component of prime faces. requirement is to navigation through pages should be done pre configured time in property file. If the configured time is 30 seconds..then pagination should be performed for every 30 seconds.

```
 <h:form>
      <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtPaginatorView.cars}" rows="10"
             paginator="true"
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} 
     {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} 
     {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Year">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Brand">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Color">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
    </p:column>

    <f:facet name="paginatorTopLeft">
        <p:commandButton type="button" icon="pi pi-refresh" />
    </f:facet>

    <f:facet name="paginatorBottomRight">
        <p:commandButton type="button" icon="pi pi-cloud-upload" />
    </f:facet>

</p:dataTable>
```

For every 30 seconds, every pages should be displayed at 30 seconds intervals

Comment: Then fake a click ont the 'next page' button from javascript every 30 seconds. Or see if the datatable component has an `nextPage` in its client-side api. Plain and simple

Comment: You can give the navigation button IDs and use JQuery to simulate clicks every 30 second

Comment: @Exorcismus: you can't assign id's to the 'navigation buttons' since they are generated. But they are otherwise easily identifieable and selectable with jquery. But usomg the native javascript api of the component is the better way.

Comment: @Kukeltje or that :)

Comment: is there any example to achieve this operation @Kukeltje